# Time series Anomaly detection in R using AnomalyDetectionTs package

Tags: r, anomaly-detection

I amusing AnomalyDetectionTs package in R to detect anomalies in 275 days however some of observation are less than 275 days

here is the data frame

[image]

and here is the number of observation in each category

[image]

But when I run the anomaly detection code I will see the following error message:

```
Error in do.ply(i) : 
  task 88 failed - "With longterm=TRUE, AnomalyDetection splits the data into 2 week periods by default. You have 103 observations in a period, which is too few. Set a higher piecewise_median_period_weeks."
```

I have set the piecewise_median_period_weeks in 40 weeks 
as follows:

```
AnomalyDetectionTs(df, max_anoms = 0.002, direction = "both", alpha = 0.05, e_value = FALSE, plot = FALSE, y_log = FALSE,longterm=TRUE,piecewise_median_period_weeks=40)
```

When I just filter those categories more than 103 observation it works fine. 
Could you please help me how to define this parameter (piecewise_median_period_weeks) that can detect all of observation.

Comment: One way that I found is to assign dynamic value into piecewise_median_period_weeks() based on the count number of each category

Comment: I was using the Python version of this package from peculiarity and faced this issue. 
A way around this was to use the alternative function detect_vec instead of detect_ts

Answer (score 1):

I've the same problem and I resolve it using something like below. I'm using future_lapply form package future.apply to increase performance.

```
future_lapply(ValuesToIterate, function(x) {
  k = 2
  repeat {
    outlier <- 
      try(
        ad_ts(y[y$var_local == x, c(var_date, var_quantityt)], max_anoms = 0.05, direction = "both",
              longterm = TRUE, na.rm = TRUE, only_last = NULL, piecewise_median_period_weeks = k)
      )
    # If there is no error return
    if (!(inherits(outlier, "try-error"))) {
      return(outlier)
    } 
    k = k + 1
    # Define a threshold
    if(k > max_k) {
      return(tibble::tibble(timestamp = NA))
    }
  }
})
```

In your example:
var_local is *category* and

ValuesToIterate is

```
unique(category)
```

Also I'm using `return(tibble::tibble(timestamp = NA))` because then I add `purrr:::map_dfr` to get a dataframe with 3 columns where some series have no anomaly so they are NA

I'd like to use data.table to resolve this but I can't because ad_ts return a timestamp numeric which break the code.